# Añadir botón favoritos en django

Tags: python, django

muy buenas, estoy haciendo una aplicación de gestión de inventarios. tengo una tabla con artículos para examinar sus características, una vez examinado el articulo, el usuario tiene la opción de añadirlo a otra tabla donde se almacenara para su puesta a la venta. el problema es que es que no consigo hacer que esto se lleve a cabo con ninguna de las estrategias que he utilizado.

En models.py:

```
inventariado = models.BooleanField(("Inventariado"), default=False)
```

En urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import catalogoproveedor

   urlpatterns = [
   path('<int:articulo_id>/', catalogoproveedor, name='catalogoproveedor'),
   ]
```

En views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from proveedores.models import ArticuloDisponible

def catalogoproveedor(request, articulo_id=None):
    articulosproveedores = ArticuloDisponible.objects.all()

    if articulo_id:
        articulo = get_object_or_404(ArticuloDisponible, id=articulo_id)
        articulo.inventariado = True
        articulo.save()

    return render(request, 'proveedores/catalogoproveedor.html', 
              {"articulosproveedores": articulosproveedores})
```

Comment: Hola, estoy viendo que primero coges todos los articulosproveedores y luego dependiendo si hay un articulo_id lo actualizas, pero ya tienes todos los articulosproveedores sin actualizar, deberias poner la sentencia: articulosproveedores = ArticuloDisponible.objects.all() justo antes del return render......